# Sending string having quote in it as post method without backslash

Tags: php, html, post, backslash, quote

We all know that sending quote as parameters will be replaced by a backslash quote.

I have 2 pages: *login.html* and *index.php*

The login page must send parameters to the index page using the POST method.

Let's say I'm sending

```
username --> X'D
password --> xxx
```

The username automatically transfers to `X\'D` .. but I want it to remain `X'D`.

How is it possible to receive the data without the backslash?

I want the backslash to be removed before arriving to the index page not using the htmlspecialchar in the index page or something.

Comment: Actually, that's not how it works. Do you have magic quotes turned on perhaps?

Comment: Check with `echo get_magic_quotes_gpc();` if you have [magicquotes](http://php.net/manual/en/security.magicquotes.php) enabled

Comment: So in case it is turned on,
can't I disable it from the code? From my page, the login.html or login.php

Comment: Follow http://php.net/manual/en/security.magicquotes.disabling.php

Comment: The link you sent me must be placed on the index.php
So you mean that there's no way that i could send the quote without being replaced by backslash quote if i don't have access to the receiving page?

Answer (score 0):

If magic-quotes is turned, there's no way to have a quote sent to the server side without backslash before it.

Thank you all for helping me.

Answer (score -1):

Try this one . :)

```
echo str_replace("\'","'","X\'D");
```

Comment: the thing is that i can't access the index.php page
all i can do is sending parameters to the index.php only